# Where can I find one of Langrage's theorems about subgroups of Symmetric groups in Herstein's book Abstract Algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

By Lagrange, every proper subgroup of a symmetric group is cyclic. But I don't know where to find this theorem in Herstein's Abstract Algebra. Anybody who has read this book give me a clue please. Or if you have read another books about abstract algebra, tell where to find this in those books.

Comment: No - Lagranges theorem states that every proper subgroup of a finite group has order dividing the order of the group, $H\leq G\Rightarrow |H|\text{ divides }|G|$. For example, $S_3$ is a proper subgroup of $S_3\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, and $S_3$ is not cyclic. However, I cannot help you with your actual question. Sorry!

Comment: (I am assuming that you have tried looking at the back of the book, in the index...)

Comment: I asked the question because in alxander's answer he mentioned that >For this particular example($S_3$), the group is small enough that you can deduce that every proper subgroup is cyclic (by Lagrange)<br/> The theorem you give here doesn't seem to be related.

Comment: It is okay, I know why you asked the question! It is just that I have never read Herstein's book. It is on p101 of Fraleigh, if that helps?

Comment: thank you, you're really help. if you could give me the link?

Comment: I only have a hard copy of Fraleigh. Sorry. However, you should look up p59 of Herstein. I know this because I found the index online...

Comment: alright. By the way, I didn't know it will help looking up the index before and you just recommanded a good document to me, so thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to look up something in a book you should first look up the index. This is the best way of doing such things, especially if the theorem is a named theorem (such as Lagrange's theorem). If it is not a named theorem then you could look up a related term, for example "order" or "subgroup", in the index and see if you can find the theorem you are after there.

If this fails, go to [google books](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=tDKHngEACAAJ&dq=herstein&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uIZCU6yOFZPN7Aa6hIGQCA&ved=0CEcQ6AEwBA) or [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471368792) and search for your key term inside the book.

Also, as I said in the comments, your statement of Lagrange's theorem is incorrect. Firstly, it holds for all finite groups, not just symmetric groups (although this does not matter by Cayley's Theorem). Lagranges theorem states that every proper subgroup of a finite group has order dividing the order of the group. $$H\leq G\Rightarrow |H| \text{ divides } |G|$$ For example, $S_3$ is a proper subgroup of $S_3\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, and $S_3$ is not cyclic.